# How do I get the author's page url from their ID?

Tags: php, functions, urls, author

What is the best way to get the author's page url, so http://example.com/author/user73, from their ID number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url